# MultiChoiceModeListener android source

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to find the code of `MultiChoiceModeListener` interface from the Android source. But all i could find is a skeleton : 
http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java#6301

It just says that it extends the ActionMode.CallBack interface, which is also just a skeleton : http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/ActionMode.java#229

Where exactly is the code that defines the behaviour of `MultiChoiceModeListner`? For example, where is the code that calls the startActionMode() when using the `MultiChoiceModeListner`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiChoiceModeListener` is an interface, so you will not find any code defining its behavior just because interface only defines methods and not their implementations(like abstract class may do).

Basicly `MultiChoiceModeWrapper` class is implementing the `MultiChoiceModeListener` and its located in AbsListView.java.

AbsListView holds `MultiChoiceModeWrapper` field `mMultiChoiceModeCallback` and uses it upon different scenarios.

Comment: Thanks. You are right that `MultiChoiceModeWrapper` in `AbsListView` implements the interface. But even that class does not do anything. It just calls the interface methods. I guess what i was looking for is defined in `ActionBarContainer.java` and `ActionBarImpl.java`.